# Chrome extension development - How do I pass info/variables/data from the content.js to the extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to achieve something very simple and I'm blocked by the not so clear explanations in the chrome extension development official website.

I am trying to build a chrome extension with one button that extract the H2 from the specific page it's on, and pass this data into the extension to be shown there in a list (or something else if more easily implemented).

So from what I read I struggle with the logics of all the files and permissions:

1. So using the message passing I was able to send this data in a way but it's only working when I reload the page when the extension is opened(clicked on), the moment I close the extension it doesn't work anymore.
2. I saw that there is a way to use scripts injection with chrome.scripting, have no idea how it works though because when I tried the official documentation example it doesn't have the mechanism of listening to when I click the button in the extension, it just fires away.
3. There is the local storage, tried it but I had hard time accessing the data it collects with clicking the button inside the extension. if it's possible at all.
4. I saw couple of guys on youtube talking about passing a message through the background.js, which I can get the data from the content.js but how do I pass it to the extension when I click the button inside of it?
5. I saw one guy on youtube using var to share the info through the "window." but I know that this might have other problems because the use of a var.

The real question is:
Is there a difference between all those ways? are there any limitations? cons/pros? are there other ways?

Where can I really learn about chrome extension development?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simply use executeScript inside a click handler for the button. Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu. To learn more you can install the [demo extensions](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-extensions-samples) and debug them in the built-in devtools debugger to see how various parts work.

Comment: You need to show examples of how you tried to use the examples from Chrome's documentation along with your manifest and which script has each piece of code.

Comment: For the first option of message passing, you just need to put the message listener in the background script, not the toolbar script. The background script is always running as long as there is an event listener and Chrome is open.

Comment: thanks @Rojo, I will try to get the event listener in the background script, but how can I make the button inside the extension pull the data into itself?

Comment: 1) What do you mean when you write "the moment I close the extension"? What type of extension is it? Is it pop-up with a button inside it? Are you adding a button to the page that you can click on? 2) It's worth noting, perhaps, that `content.js` isn't passing anything "to the extension" - it's _part_ of the extension along with the `background,js`, icons, manifest, and any other scripts you add.

Comment: @TryingToLearn you can access global variables stored in the background page from the popup script using [`getBackgroundPage()`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#method-getBackgroundPage)

Comment: @Andy pop-up with a button inside it

Comment: Thanks @Rojo , I'm going to try everything you just said :) Is there a way to know which way is the most efficient? fast? out of all the ways I wrote in the main question

Comment: You measure the speed of the functions yourself using `console.log(performance.now())` before and after each function and then subtracting the values. That'll be the time in ms.